# Extract log probabilities from MulinomialNB

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have a scikit-learn `Pipeline` made of a feature extractor, and a `VotingClassifier`, which contains `MulinomialNB` and some other models. When I train `MulinomialNB` separately I can extract the log probabilities using `nb.feature_log_prob_`, but inside a pipeline this attribute is missing.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

vclf =  Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('clf', VotingClassifier(
        estimators=[
            ('nb', MultinomialNB()),
            [...]
        ]
    ))
])
vclf.fit(train_X, train_y)

nb = vclf.named_steps['clf'].estimators[0][1]
nb.feature_log_prob_
```

> AttributeError: 'MultinomialNB' object has no attribute 'feature_log_prob_'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html?highlight=voting#sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier), `estimators_` is the correct attribute to access the list of **fitted** sub-estimators of the `VotingClassifier`. Your code should therefore look like this:

```
nb = vclf.named_steps['clf'].estimators_[0]
print(nb.feature_log_prob_)
```

The `MulinomialNB` you accessed with `estimators` was not fitted and, therefore, did not provide the `feature_log_prob_` attribute. That is where the error came from.